# code first in EF doesn't create database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 projects in my solution as you can see :

[image]

I want to use code first to create my database so my code to create the model is :

```
   namespace CMSDataLayer
{
   public class CMSDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public CMSDataContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

      Database.SetInitializer(
        new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CMSDataContext, CMSMigrationsConfiguration>()
        );
    }
        public DbSet<table1> Topics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
 public class CMSMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CMSDataContext>
    {

        public CMSMigrationsConfiguration()
        {
            this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

    }
    }
```

I added the connection string to MVC project webconfig

after running the database isn't created .I put a break point in CMSDataContext  class but the break point never called.why ?

I am so new in EF code first .

best regards

Comment: I would never use either of these flags `this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`

Comment: I added the CMSdatalayer to my mvc project

Comment: @EricJ. why dear friend?

Comment: did You connect to database using Server Explorer ??

Comment: `View -> Server Explorer
Right click on Data Connections and select Add Connection`…
If you haven’t connected to a database from Server Explorer before you’ll need to select Microsoft SQL Server as the data source

Comment: @Webruster no i didn't

Comment: If you enable automatic migrations, you are not carefully managing changes to the schema of your production database.  If you allow for data loss, well, that's usually not a good thing in a production database :-)  If I'm doing something that causes data loss (dropping a column, or shortening one) I would rather the DB inform me and let me make sure that is what I really intend than have it automatically applied to production data.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar please do that

Comment: @Webruster i got the error of login to database

Comment: @EhsanAkbar pelase refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj193542.aspx is this u are connecting?

Comment: I put a break point in CMSDataContext  class but the break point never called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project you didnt made any DB connections Manually here how it shows :

`View -> Server Explorer Right click on Data Connections and select Add Connection…`
If you haven’t connected to a database from Server Explorer before you’ll need to select Microsoft SQL Server as the data source

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj193542.aspx) is an article explains how to add EF

Comment: I put a break point in CMSDataContext  class but the break point never called

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it will create the database not before it's used.
Try to add a entity to the database and see if it creates it then.

You can use the seeding function if you want to add some dummy data:
[seeding tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I put a break point in CMSDataContext  class but the break point never called